# OpenCV VideoWriter become slower and slower

Tags: python, performance, opencv

I am writing images to video with `VideoWriter`from `OpenCV` on Mac OS X. Here's the code:

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'avc1')
vw = cv2.VideoWriter('%s/%s' % (path, 'output.avi'),
    fourcc, fps, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]), True)
for fn in filenames:
    img = cv2.imread('%s/%s.png' % (path, fn))
    if img == None:
        print 'bad file', fn
        continue
    else:
        print 'writing', fn
    #cv2.imshow('preview', img)
    #cv2.waitKey(1)
    vw.write(img)
```

This codes runs good at beginning (10 frames written per second). Then, it become slower and slower until it dropped to a unacceptable level. After 1 hours (Yes, I have a lot of files, ~10k), it becomes roughly 30 seconds for one frame. After 3 hours, more than 1 minutes required for writing one frame.

I checked `Activity Monitor`, `QTKitServer` consumes about 10% CPU and <40M memory. Why it becomes so slow? Is there anything wrong in my code? How can I improve the performance?

Some info:

All images I have are put under a single folder, they are all 1080p `.png` files. FPS is about `1000/66~=15`. It took me 6 hours to generate one video, which is ~500MB.

I run this code on a Mac OS X 10.10.5 computer with Xeon E3-1225v3, 16GB RAM. `OpenCV` is installed with `brew install opencv3`. Memory usage maintains around 6GB and cache is 7GB. Swap usage is ~=12MB.

Comment: As a work around have you considered using intermediate files, say generate each 1 minute of video into a separate file and then using FFMPEG to merge them?

Comment: What is the fourcc code?

Comment: Can you please check the total amount of memory (or rather, swap usage) used while running? What you are observing could be an issue of image data being left in memory, causing swapping.

Comment: not sure about OS X but on Debian I had problems writing files (single file for each image). Worked well for some time but later there were some longer delays. Probably some file system optimizations... Try to do the file writing with some custom buffering in a separate thread! this worked for me. I could see some buffer growing after some time but buffer shrinking later again. However you should check whether bandwith for writing on your device is big enough!!

Comment: @HannesOvrén Swap usage is 12MB only and memory usage is less than half (6G/16G total). So I think it is not the problem.

Comment: @Micka Thanks for your suggestions... I also checked the disk IO: Read ~= 3MB/sec, Write ~=200KB/sec.